# Change the color of a specified item in a listview for android

Tags: android, android-listview

I would like to change the text color of only one item in a listview.

This change will be triggered by the result of a running asynctask.

So far I searched on google and all I found was to overwrite the getView() function of the adapter, but this approach is kind of hard since I would need to keep the id of the rows I want to color in a global variable that will be accessed by getView().

Is there another way to simply set the text color of an item from a listview when an event happens ?

**EDIT**

I create the listview this way:

```
myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow);
listAdapter.add("test");
myListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: How do you create your ListView? If by creating a list of SimpleCursorAdapter you can change the color with ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting a color for a list item definitely you need to override the `getView()` method of the `Adapter`. Here is a small example for updating the color of the list item without using the id of the item.

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow) {
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    if (position % 2 == 0) {  //Place the condition where you want to change the item color.
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    } else {
                         //Setting to default color.
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                    return view;
                }
            };
```

In the above example, all the list item at even number positions will be in `GREY` color and others will be `WHITE` color. We cannot do this without implementing the `getView()`. For reference [Click Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup))

Answer (score 0):

You may set custom object vis color in adapter then change color in this adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I am new to Android programming ... didn't quite understand your answer. What you are saying implies to overwrite getView(). I wanted to know if there is another way.