# Android change TextView Font color in a ListView for a condition

Tags: android, listview, getview

I have same problem as [Change the color of a specified item in a listview for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127473/change-the-color-of-a-specified-item-in-a-listview-for-android) answered by [Kartheek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3338360/kartheek) (Thank you) and adapted for testing as follows:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.db_msg,messaggi){
      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
          View view1 = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
//          if (position % 2 == 0) {  //Place the condition where you want 
to change the item color.
         testo = messaggi.get(position);
          if(testo.substring(0,5).equals("27-09")){
           view1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e0e0ef"));
        } else {
            //Setting to default color.
            view1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        return view1;
      }
    };
```

**Question:** I rather change font Color but view1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E0E0EF"); does not seem to work;

Comment: write    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e0e0ef"));

Comment: include your db_msg layout xml code

Comment: show us this layout R.layout.db_msg

Comment: Sorry looks like I created some confusion. The code shown works very well,but it changes background color not text color so I tried view1.setTextColor and android studio flags it red "cannot resolve method setTextColor.  db_msg.xml 
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/db_msg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show Us **db_msg** this layout in that layout there is one TextView just get the name of that and replace with "tvIDFrom_db_msg_layout" this

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.db_msg,messaggi){
      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
   {
          View view1 = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
         if (position % 2 == 0) {  //Place the condition where you want to change the item color.
             testo = messaggi.get(position);
              TextView tvText = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.tvIDFrom_db_msg_layout);
            if(testo.substring(0,5).equals("27-09")){

                 tvText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#yourHexCode"));
            } else {
                //Setting to default color.
                tvText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        return view1;
      }
    };
```

Comment: Yes it works!! I was able to use                  tvText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000ef"));

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed the last closing ')' in your command. Otherwise it seams correct:

```
view1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E0E0EF"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View view1;
 view1=convertView;
 if (convertView == null) {
        view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.db_msg, null);
        testo = messaggi.get(position);
        if(testo.substring(0,5).equals("27-09")){
        view1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e0e0ef"));
    } 
else {
         //Setting to default color.
         view1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
       return convertView;
}
```